# A definite char appearing at same location two strings

Tags: java, string

When I input string as 

abc--rd
acdr--d

it checks for the first instance of - in both strings and then enters the if condition(commented as MARK1)

**PROBLEM:** even if there is '-' in only one of the string it enters the if condition

A sample output tested using the commented parts 
Ayan--kr
--Ayankr
char Pos: 0
st1: - st2: -
true
char Pos: 1
st1: - st2: -
true
same pattern

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringpattern{
      public static boolean stringPattern(String s1,String s2){
            String st1=s1.length()<s2.length()?s1:s2;//larger string in st1
            String st2=s1.length()>s2.length()?s1:s2;//smaller string in st2
            boolean b=false;
            //int cou=0;
            String s=st2.substring(st1.length());//taking extra string of st2 in s
            if(s.contains("-"))//false if extra string contains '-'
                  b=false;
            else{

                  for(int i=0;i<st1.length();i++)
                  {
                        if((st1.charAt(i)=='-') && (st2.charAt(i)=='-'))//MARK1
                        {
            //It enters the if condition even if there is a '-' in only one string

                              //System.out.println("Char Pos: "+cou);
                              //System.out.println("st1: "+st1.charAt(i)"+" st2: "+st2.charAt(i));
                              b=true;


                              //System.out.println(b);  
                        }
                       // cou++;
                  }

            }
            return b;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            String s1=s.next();
            String s2=s.next();
            boolean b=stringPattern(s1,s2);
            if(b==true)
                  System.out.println("same pattern");
            else
                  System.out.println("different pattern");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
String st1=s1.length()<s2.length()?s1:s2;//larger string in st1
String st2=s1.length()>s2.length()?s1:s2;//smaller string in st2
```

You are giving two strings of the same length, so both of these conditions are false and you are setting both `st1` and `st2` to `s2`

I will also pre-empt the index out of bounds issues you will be getting:

```
for(int i=0;i<st1.length();i++)
{
    if((st1.charAt(i)=='-') && (st2.charAt(i)=='-'))
```

As st1 should be the longer string (according to you, I'm not sure what you will implement when you fix the other problems), You will get to a point where i >= st2.length(), you should only search up to the end of the shorter string to avoid this.

Comment: Also there should be else { b=false; } after if condition. Otherwise conditions such as Ayan-- and Ayan -+ will give same pattern as output as b value will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

@moreON explained the problem.

 The corrected program is here. 
PROBLEM 1: The ternary operator was the problem
PROBLEM 2: The else case of if should update b=false if later string does not match

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringpattern{
      public static boolean stringPattern(String s1,String s2){
            String st1=s1.length()<s2.length()?s2:s1;//larger string in st1
            String st2=s1.length()>s2.length()?s1:s2;//smaller string in st2
            boolean b=false;
            //int cou=0;
            String s=st2.substring(st1.length());//taking extra string of st2 in s
            if(s.contains("-"))//false if extra string contains '-'
                  b=false;
            else{

                  for(int i=0;i<st1.length();i++)
                  {
                        if((st1.charAt(i)=='-') && (st2.charAt(i)=='-'))//MARK1
                        {
            //It enters the if condition even if there is a '-' in only one string

                              //System.out.println("Char Pos: "+cou);
                              //System.out.println("st1: "+st1.charAt(i)"+" st2: "+st2.charAt(i));
                              b=true;


                              //System.out.println(b);  
                        }
                        else{b=false;}
                       // cou++;
                  }

            }
            return b;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            String s1=s.next();
            String s2=s.next();
            boolean b=stringPattern(s1,s2);
            if(b==true)
                  System.out.println("same pattern");
            else
                  System.out.println("different pattern");
      }
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually explain what the overall output of the function should be. Could you explain precisely under what conditions you want it to return false and what conditions you want it to return true? Based on what those conditions actually are right now, I doubt that they are what you are intended - but they might be, can't be sure.

Comment: If the strings are different lengths, I think this now doesn't work, try it.